# не могу установить InputSimulator

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

В общем, устанавливаю я `InputSimulator`, и вижу
код в терминале:

```
install-package InputSimulator
error: install-package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'InputSimulator'. Try Get-PackageSource to see all available registered package sources.
at line:1 char:1 
+install-package InputSimulator
+~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:installPackage) [install-package], Exception
```

Comment: это вроде [делается так](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-dotnet-cli) `dotnet add package InputSimulator`. Либо вот еще почитайте https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/package-management